# Bowling Game Program - Assertion Error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertions

I am in the somewhat beginning stages of creating a bowling program in Java. I currently have a JUnit test file called BowlingGameTest and a Java class called Game...both of these are under my Java project, BowlingGame. I have the following code in my BowlingGameTest file:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class BowlingGameTest extends TestCase {
    private Game g;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        g = new Game();
    }

    private void rollMany (int n, int pins) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            g.roll(pins);
        }
    }

    public void testGutterGame() throws Exception {
        rollMany(20,0);
        assertEquals(0, g.score());
    }

    public void testAllOnes() throws Exception {
        rollMany(20,1);
        assertEquals(20, g.score());
    }

    public void testOneSpare() throws Exception {
        rollSpare();
        g.roll(3);
        rollMany(17,0);
        assertEquals(16,g.score());
    }

    public void testOneStrike() throws Exception {
        g.roll(10); //strike
        g.roll(3);
        g.roll(4);
        rollMany(16,0);
        assertEquals(24, g.score());
    }

    private void rollSpare() {
        g.roll(5);
        g.roll(5);
    }
}
```

and the following code in my Java class, Game:

```
public class Game {
    private int rolls[] = new int[21];
    private int currentRoll = 0;

    public void roll(int pins) {
        rolls[currentRoll++] = pins;
    }

    public int score() {
        int score = 0;
        int frameIndex = 0;
        for (int frame = 0; frame < 10; frame++) {
            if (rolls[frameIndex] == 10) //strike
            {
                score += 10 +
                        rolls[frameIndex + 1] +
                        rolls[frameIndex + 2];
                frameIndex++;
            }
            else if (isSpare(frameIndex))
            {
                score += 10 + rolls[frameIndex + 2];
                frameIndex += 2;
            }   else {
                score += rolls[frameIndex] +
                         rolls[frameIndex+1];
                frameIndex += 2;
            }
        }
        return score;
    }

    private boolean isSpare(int frameIndex) {
        return rolls[frameIndex] +
            rolls[frameIndex + 1] == 10;
    }
}
```

I keep getting 2 errors when testing my program:
[image]

How can I fix this? I know I can simply change the numbers in my assertEquals code, but I am wanting those numbers, 16 and 24.

Comment: What did you find when you debugged your program?

Comment: @Pillar Whenever I debug my program, all I find are those 2 errors which I posted above in my original question

Comment: No, what did you find when you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @Pillar okay so I just noticed something...if i test the file, BowlingGameTest, it says there are 2 errors like it says above...but if i test the entire project, BowlingGame, then it says all 4 tests passed...why is that?